# Autosys - Get Jobs list on a specific computer

Tags: autosys, jil

I try to get the list of **all the jobs** running on **a specific client.**

When running `autorep -J ALL -q`  I get the following output:

```
 /* ----------------- ### ----------------- */

  insert_job: ###   job_type: CMD
  box_name: ###
  command: ###
  machine: MACHINE X
  owner: autosys
  permission:
  date_conditions: ###
  condition: ###
  description: ###
  box_terminator: 1
  alarm_if_fail: 0
  application: ###


  /* ----------------- ### ----------------- */

  insert_job: ###   job_type: CMD
  box_name: ###
  command: ###
  machine: MACHINE Y
  owner: autosys
  permission:
  date_conditions: ###
  condition: ###
  description: ###
  box_terminator: 1
  alarm_if_fail: 0
  application: ### 

  ...
```

As you can see, is displayed here the list of **ALL the jobs** for **ALL the clients**

What I expect to get is an output as following :

```
 /* ----------------- ### ----------------- */

  insert_job: ###   job_type: CMD
  box_name: ###
  command: ###
  machine: MACHINE X
  owner: autosys
  permission:
  date_conditions: ###
  condition: ###
  description: ###
  box_terminator: 1
  alarm_if_fail: 0
  application: ###


  /* ----------------- ### ----------------- */

  insert_job: ###   job_type: CMD
  box_name: ###
  command: ###
  machine: MACHINE X
  owner: autosys
  permission:
  date_conditions: ###
  condition: ###
  description: ###
  box_terminator: 1
  alarm_if_fail: 0
  application: ### 

  ...
```

Unfortunately the commands `autorep -J ALL -q -m MACHINE X` doesn't work but give me the following output :

```
/* ----------------- MACHINE X ----------------- */

insert_machine: MACHINE X
type: a
factor: 1.00
port: 7520
node_name: MACHINE X
agent_name: WA_AGENT
encryption_type: DEFAULT
opsys: windows
character_code: ASCII
```

I guess that this is the JIL format to add a machine, so what no I expect to get.

Do you know if what I try to do is possible using autosys commands only or if I have to parse the first output trough some regex to finally obtain what I would like to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally created a script that does it for me :

```
#!/bin/ksh
autorep -j ALL -q > alljobs.jil
mkdir /tmp/autosystemp
i=0
while IFS=\| read -r "line"; do
        if [ `echo $line | grep '/* ------' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then
                i=$((i+1))
        fi
        echo "$line" >> "/tmp/autosystemp/f$i"
done < alljobs.jil
rm tempo/f0
for file in /tmp/autosystemp/*; do
        while read line; do
                if [ `echo $line | grep "machine: $1" | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then
                        cat $file >> "jobs-on-$1.jil"
                fi
        done < $file
done
rm -rf /tmp/autosystemp
```

To use it just pass the machine name as an argument to the script

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Autosys Jill parser , using that you can have required info in csv file .After that you can filter required information

first you must have a file which contains required columns to be extracted from jill like

```
$]cat Jill_Columns
insert_job
job_type
box_name
watch_file
watch_interval
command
date_conditions
machine
owner
permission
condition
days_of_week
exclude_calendar
start_times
description
std_out_file
std_err_file
alarm_if_fail
profile
application
```

and Jill file which needs to be parsed to csv

Here is the script

Command to run in unix box

sh JillToCsv.sh Your_Jill_Columns Yours_Jill_file

```
#!/bin/bash



Usage()
{
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo " "
echo " "
echo " "
echo "This script takes two parameter "
echo "First is the file which conatins column names like below for Jill information "
echo "cat Jill_ColumnOrder.txt"
echo "insert_job
job_type
box_name
command
date_conditions
machine
owner
permission
condition
days_of_week
exclude_calendar
start_times
description
std_out_file
std_err_file
alarm_if_fail
profile
application"

echo " "
echo " "
echo " "
echo "Second is the Jill File which needs to be parsed as csv "
echo " "
echo " "
echo " "
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}

if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
echo "File which contains column names  : $1"
echo "Input Jill File                   : $2"
else
echo "Please pass manadatory parameters"
Usage
exit 1
fi


Jill_ColumnOrder=$1


tfile=$2

dos2unix $tfile

final=${tfile}_Parse.csv
rm -f $final


heading=`cat $Jill_ColumnOrder|sed 's/$/@Akhilesh@/g'|sed '$ s/@Akhilesh@$//g'|tr -d '\n'`

line=
filler=1


no_columns=`cat $Jill_ColumnOrder|wc -l`


while [ $filler -lt $no_columns ]
do
        filler=`expr $filler + 1`
        line=$line`echo -n "@Akhilesh@"`
        #echo $line
done

#echo "$heading"
#echo "   "
#echo "$line"



echo "$heading">$final



count=1
cat $tfile|sed -r 's/job_type/\njob_type/g'|sed '/^$/d'|sed -r 's/\s+/ /g'|while read kk
do
        echo "$kk"|sed -r 's/^[ ]+//g'|grep '\/\* -----------------' # >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                count=`expr $count + 1`
                echo "$line">>$final
        else
        PP=`echo $kk|cut -d ':' -f1|tr -d ' '`
        #echo "PP    : $PP"
        val=`echo $kk|cut -d ':' -f2-|sed -r 's/^[ ]+//g'|tr -d '"'|tr -d '\n'`
        #echo $val
        val=\"$val\"
        field=`grep -nw $PP $Jill_ColumnOrder|cut -d':' -f1|tr -d '\n'`

        #echo "field   :  $field"

        if [ -z $field ]
        then
        echo "$PP not there in column list"
        else

        awk -F'@Akhilesh@' -v OFS=@Akhilesh@ -v var="$val" -v var1=$count '{if(NR== var1) $'$field' = var;print}' $final > tmp.parse && mv tmp.parse $final
        fi



        fi
done




cat $final|sed 's/@Akhilesh@/,/g' > tmp.parse && mv tmp.parse $final
```

Answer (score 0):

autorep does not support that sorting as of yet. You will need to parse out the output.

Dave

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but probably and sadly true - thanks anyway